# XPath 2.0: how to test that we have in a variable is an element?

Tags: xpath

Say I have a variable `$foo`. I'd like to use `$foo castable as element()`, but I can't use a node type after castable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$foo instance of element()` does the trick.